# Why is there no hot reload in jetpack compose? Is it theoretically possible for them to add flutter like hot-reloads in compose in future?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, android-jetpack-compose, hot-reload

I'm trying to understand why can't we have hot reloads with jetpack compose and kotlin. I understand flutter sends the code and rebuilds the widget tree but why can't we achieve similar with jetpack compose?

If I had to make a third party tool to enable hot reloads, how would I proceed to make it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a Live Edit function available in Electric Eel Canary builds of Android Studio. It is still experimental but works well. You can find the details here: [Iterative Code Development](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#iterative-code-dev)

"Starting with Android Studio Electric Eel, you can accelerate your Compose development experience by using Live Edit. Live Edit is a more powerful version of Live edit of literals. The functionality allows you to see the effect of updates to composables in real time by automatically updating the Preview and deploying code changes to an emulator or device."

I believe this is very close to Flutter Hot Reload.

Comment: "Live Edit refreshes Compose Preview when changes are made to UI elements." That's what hot reload does if I remember correctly from my Flutter days... ;-)

Comment: Holy shit! I had no idea about this! I just downloaded the preview build and tested it and it's awesome. Any idea how are they achieving this?

Comment: Glad it helped! No idea how they do it. :-)

Comment: By the way, don't forget to accept the answer if your question is solved.